# How to show the label for couple of seconds and show another label in form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, label

I have a mini form3 https://imageshack.com/i/p1zxB6Lqp which shows a gif image running for 4 sec. So i need to show 4 different
labels in same position..

For example

```
label 1 - `Connecting to smtp server..`
label 2 - `Fetching recipients..`
label 3 - `Attaching necessary G-code files..`
label 4 - `Please wait sending..`
```

How can i show all these labels one after another in same position.. so it looking more professional
for sending mail.

My code snippet:-

**Form1**

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //mail inforamtion
    _f3.ShowDialog(); // - - >> is the form i wanted with all labels
    smtp.Send(msg);
    MessageBox.Show("Email Successfully Sent!!!", "Mail!!!.");
    Environment.Exit(0);

}
```

**Form3:**

```
    Timer formCloser = new Timer();
    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = 5000;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        timer1.Stop();
    }
```

Please help me out.. how can i add label in my form..

Comment: why do they need to be different label?  why not just change the text?

Comment: @Plutonix any thing is fine for unless it do the job!! :P

Comment: @Plutonix any ideas!!!!!. could you post your answer// and i will try it//

Comment: `statusLabel.Text = strMessageToDisplay;` the timer seems pointless if you are reporting on the status of soemthing; better to update the text when your code detects the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.. I kept two timers for each function,

timer1 to run the mini form only for 5 seconds.
and timer two to run only for 1 sec. **If any body has a better code to share with please..
Most welcome!!**

Here is my code:

```
     private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = 5000;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);

        timer2.Interval = 1000;
        timer2.Start();
    }


    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        timer1.Stop();
    }

    int StopTime = 0;
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StopTime++;
        if (StopTime == 1)
        {
            label1.Text = "  Connecting to smtp server..";
        }
        if (StopTime == 2)
        {
            label1.Text = "     Fetching recipients..";
        }
        if (StopTime == 3)
        {
            label1.Text = "  Attaching G-code files..";
        }
        if (StopTime == 4)
        {
            label1.Text = "                Done!!";
            StopTime = 0;
            timer2.Stop();
        }
    }
```